# Magento 2 category listing page mixed with static images

Tags: magento2, category, template, product-grid

I am working on a Magento 2.1 site and on the category product listing page I want to display static images mixed with actual product images.

So for example I would have a row of say 4 images across but every other image would be an image that is not part of or linked to any specific product.

I know there is a platform called Olapic that will let you show user generated content inter mixed with the product listing as shown in the image below:

[image: https://ibb.co/gXObGa]

However I was wondering how this may be achieved. I don't necessarily want user generated content from social platforms but instead static images I would upload to our site. Ideas/suggestions?